# a command line or a script who is able to display each version of each element archived in a vob since the beginning?

Tags: command-line, scripting, clearcase

For example,

```
I am in a vob called: avob
I add to source control a folder:
avob/afolder
I add to source control two files afile1 and afile2
avob/afolder/afile1
avob/afolder/afile2
I uncatalogued the file afile2
I add to source control afile3
avob/afolder/afile3
```

I would like (a command line or a script who is able to) display each version of each element archived since the beginning, here:

```
avob@version1
avob@version2
avob@version2/afile1@version1
avob@version2/afile2@version1
avob@version3
avob@version3/afile1@version1
avob@version4
avob@version4/afile1@version1
avob@version4/afile3@version1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only command which could come close of what you are looking for would be

```
ct lshist vob:\yourVob
```

which would list all the events  for all versions of all files (add to source control, rmname, merges, ...)

But that would involve a lot of parsing of a huge log file if your vob has a few years of history...

Answer (score 1):

A script could scan the entire VOB for all its elements/history and generate a report.

If you wanted to script it, you'd start by collecting version information on the root dir of the vob:

```
cleartool lsvtree -all /vobs/myvob/
```

It would list all the versions of the root dir of the VOB, and then you could lsvtree every single version of that dir for every element in every version of the root dir, keeping track of them all and recursing into directory versions, etc., until you have all the elements and versions cataloged. It could use a lot of memory.

It will take a long time, as Von points out.